# JavaScript Helper | startsWith( ) is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to write a **helper function** that loops through an array of objects & filters all names that meet established criteria. In my case all names that begin with `Zach`

Array example:

```
const users = [
  {
    firstName: "Zach",
    id: 1,
    lastName: "Volsk"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Surly",
    id: 2,
    lastName: "Furious"
  },

  {
    firstName: "Zach",
    id: 3,
    lastName: "Tee"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Eve",
    id: 4,
    lastName: "Zelda"
  },

  {
    firstName: "Zachary",
    id: 5,
    lastName: "Toys"
  }
];
```

I'm able to retrieve the desired result applying filter and map directly i.e:

```
const filterZach = users
  .filter(user => user.firstName.startsWith("Zach"))
  .map(user => {
    return `<p>${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</p>`;
  }).join(""); // get rid of comas
```

Desired Result: `Zach Volsk, Zach Tee, Zachary Toys`

**However,** when I tried to abstract that functionality into a helper method so that I can use it elsewhere in my code:
i.e:

```
// helper
function filteredNames(arr, str) {
  return arr.filter(i => i.startsWith(str));
}
```

I get an error saying: *i.startsWith is not a function*

```
const filterZach = filteredNames(users, "Zach") // i.startsWith is not a function
const renderZach = filterZach.map(user => {
    return `<p>${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</p>`;
  }).join("");
```

**Question:** Could you please help understand the reason for this issue showing me an alternative to accomplish my goal using a helper function?

I'm not married to the `startsWith( )` method and I'd love to learn other ways to go about this. Reduce perhaps?

here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7nn6k00w9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `filteredNames`, with `arr.filter(i`, `i` is an *object*, not a string, and objects don't have a `startsWith` method. Reference the object's `firstName` instead, and call `startsWith` on it:

```
// helper
function filteredNames(arr, str) {
  return arr.filter(i => i.firstName.startsWith(str));
}
```

```js
const users = [
  {
    firstName: "Zach",
    id: 1,
    lastName: "Volsk"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Surly",
    id: 2,
    lastName: "Furious"
  },

  {
    firstName: "Zach",
    id: 4,
    lastName: "Tee"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Eve",
    id: 5,
    lastName: "Zelda"
  },

  {
    firstName: "Zachary",
    id: 6,
    lastName: "Toys"
  }
];
// helper
function filteredNames(arr, str) {
  return arr.filter(i => i.firstName.startsWith(str));
}
const filterZach = filteredNames(users, "Zach") // i.startsWith is not a function
const renderZach = filterZach.map(user => {
    return `<p>${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</p>`;
  }).join("");
document.body.innerHTML += renderZach;
```

For a dynamic property name to call `startsWith` on, pass that property name to `filteredNames`, eg

```
function filteredNames(arr, str, prop) {
  return arr.filter(i => i[prop].startsWith(str));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance, my only issue is that the helper function won't have a clue of what `firstName` is. My idea is to have that helper exist and be imported from a separate file. Please see my added sandbox

Comment: You could pass the property name to call `startsWith` on to `filteredNames`, if you wanted, I guess? It depends on the sort of logic you want

Comment: See edit, pass another parameter and use bracket notation

Comment: then I'd have to invoke the method like `filteredNames(users, "Zach", users.firstName)` ?

Comment: @NullisTrue no, `filteredNames(users, 'Zach', 'firstName')`

Comment: I appreciate you guys help, I was not familiar with bracket notation.